# ipython not recognizing alreading installed PySide?

Tags: qt, ipython

I'm using IPython 0.13.2 and I wanted to try out the IPython on QT console. However, after doing easy_install on PySide and it installed version 1.2.0. Doing ipython qtconsole still gives the same error:

```
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 352, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 40, in import_item
    module = __import__(package,fromlist=[obj])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\qt\console\qtconsoleapp.py", line 56, in <module>
    from IPython.external.qt import QtCore, QtGui
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt.py", line 57, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Cannot import PySide >= 1.0.3 or PyQt4 >= 4.7')
ImportError: Cannot import PySide >= 1.0.3 or PyQt4 >= 4.7
```

However, when I start up IPython and try to import PySide, it sees it fine:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import PySide

In [2]: PySide.__version__
Out[2]: '1.2.0'

In [3]:
```

What gives? I'm on windows XP, using Console2 (recommended on IPython website) but also try command prompt with same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem:

I need to first upgrade from Python 2.7.3 to Python 2.7.5 since PySide 1.2 was built with 2.7.5.

Afterwards, I just need to do easy_install on pygments
Then `ipython qtconsole` worked fine!